# Change style of Leaflet CircleMarker's tooltip

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, tooltip

I am using Leaflet within ReactJS for my web application.

I need to add a tooltip for my `CircleMarker` object, but its size is too small, so I need to change its width, heightv,etc.

As I got from other sources, I need to define new CSS class and give it to the `classname` prop within the tooltip. Is there any other way to handle this?

Here is my code.

```
 var marker = L.circleMarker(coordinate, {color: colorCodes[i], fillColor: colorCodes[i], fill: colorCodes[i],fillOpacity: 1.0});
marker.bindTooltip(Point.Name.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this CSS :

```
.leaflet-tooltip {
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px !important;
}
```

Then use inspect element to have your desire size in live.

If you want to use a custom css class you can add it like an option to your tooltip :

```
var tooltip = L.tooltip({
    className: "temporaire"
}).setContent(Point.Name.toString());

var marker = L.circleMarker(coordinate,{
    color: colorCodes[i],
    fillColor: colorCodes[i],
    fill: colorCodes[i],
    fillOpacity: 1.0
    }).bindTooltip(tooltip);
```

Comment: Actually, I want to add css class to my JS file and it seems I'm living problems with this - syntax. It may seem ridiculous, I know, since it should be simple. But right now, I cannot add css class to my JS. file to give this class as classname in bindTooltip method.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand everything sorry. Can you show me your CSS ?